# IPython SQL Magic - Generate Query String Programmatically

Tags: sql, ipython, ipython-magic

I'm generating SQL programmatically so that, based on certain parameters, the query that needs to be executed could be different (i.e., tables used, unions, etc). How can I insert a string like this: "select * from table", into a %%sql block?  I know that using :variable inserts variable into the %%sql block, but it does so as a string, rather than sql code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer was staring me in the face:

```
query="""
select 
*
from
sometable
"""
%sql $query
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to templatize your queries, you can use `string.Template`:

```py
from string import Template

template = Template("""
SELECT *
FROM my_data
LIMIT $limit
""")

limit_one = template.substitute(limit=1)
limit_two = template.substitute(limit=2)
```

```py
%sql $limit_one
```

Source: [JupySQL](https://jupysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#templated-sql-queries) documentation.

**Important:** If you use this approach, ensure you trust/sanitize the input!

Comment: The link no longer works, but the approach is effective and elegant, thanks!